# How to skip forward to first whitespace character?

Tags: whitespace, motion

What is the easiest way to skip forward to the first whitespace character after the current cursor?  I used to do it just by searching for a space (when I knew there was one there), but now that seems to behave like `forward-whitespace` (not sure when this behavior switched, maybe when I transitioned to emacs 24.  This is a function I need all the time when defining macros interactively.

Fwiw, `forward-whitespace` doesn't work for me because it skips to the last whitespace character in the first block of whitespace after the current cursor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `skip-syntax-forward` to skip *non*-whitespace.  Docstring:

> `(skip-syntax-forward SYNTAX &optional LIM)`
>
> Move point forward across chars in specified syntax classes.
>   SYNTAX is a string of syntax code characters.
>   Stop before a char whose syntax is not in SYNTAX, or at position LIM.
>   **If SYNTAX starts with ^, skip characters whose syntax is NOT in SYNTAX.**
>   This function returns the distance traveled, either zero or positive.

If you want to use it interactively, you can wrap it in an interactive command:

```
(defun skip-to-next-whitespace ()
  "Move point forward to next whitespace character."
  (interactive)
  (skip-syntax-forward "^\s"))
```